# Which one "in to" or "into"? They've tricked him (in to/ into) going

Tags: prepositions

What is the correct prepositions for the sentence

> They've tricked him into going.

or

> They've tricked him in to going.

Comment: Both sentences are missing an object. Are you trying to use the passive: they've been tricked into going, or the active e.g they've tricked him into going?

Comment: The active one.

Comment: I don't think this should be closed as answerable by a dictionary, even though it might seem obvious. That there are many articles that discuss "into versus in to" just emphasizes that this is a common issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Into" is correct in that sentence. From the definition of "into" in *Webster's Third New International Dictionary, Unabridged*:

> 7 a — used as a function word to indicate a set of circumstances, a
>   function, action, or occupation entered upon or taken on
>
> <get into trouble>
>   <go into business>
>   <force into compliance>
>   <might be tortured into divulging military
>   information — G. A. Craig>

Answer (score -1):

"They've tricked him into going." is correct. You can't usually double up prepositions unless there is a grammar rule backing it up.

Grammar rules that allow doubling prepositions:

1) Certain prepositions are compound. For example, "as of".

2) [Prepositional adverbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepositional_adverb) and phrasal verb adverbs can occur next to a prepositional phrase. For example, "He came inside to get warm" or "My boss sat in to audit the meeting."

Another way that you know that "They've tricked him in to going" is incorrect is if you eliminate the "to going", the sentence no longer makes sense. "They've tricked him in." What does that mean? It is not grammatically correct and does not make sense.

More info at [Writer's Digest: Into vs. In To](http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/into-vs-in-to).

Comment: Very few people use `this format` to highlight things on ELL or ELU. It might be used on other cites and perhaps it's a code for coding, which is not really apropos here. It sure makes your answer hard to read. People usually use *italics*.